# Broken Pipe error when invoking a REST service deployed in a Docker Container

Tags: docker, tensorflow, nginx, keras, docker-container

I have a REST endpoint that is deployed in a docker container using

**Dockerfile snippet**

```
ENTRYPOINT service nginx start | tensorflow_model_server --rest_api_port=8501 \
 --model_name= <modelname> \
 --model_base_path=/<Saved model path>
```

The REST endpoint is for a Tensorflow model.

I am using NGINX to accept the requests and route them to the REST endpoint

**nginx.conf snippet**

```
listen 8080 deferred;

    client_max_body_size 500M;

    location /invocations {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8501/v1/models/<modelname>:predict;
    }

    location /ping {
      return 200 "OK";
    }
```

Docker desktop version: 2.1.0.5
OS: macOS High Sierra 10.13.4

Invoking this service worked fine all this while but now throws the below Broken Pipe error starting yesterday. Can someone please help?

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ls_spiderman/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 672, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/Users/ls_spiderman/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 387, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/Users/ls_spiderman/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/Users/ls_spiderman/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Users/ls_spiderman/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Users/ls_spiderman/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1065, in _send_output
    self.send(chunk)
  File "/Users/ls_spiderman/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 986, in send
    self.sock.sendall(data)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Comment: Typically practice would be to run nginx and the application in two separate containers.  The way you've used a shell pipe, when the `service` command exits, you'll get the error you show.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks. I am a bit new to docker config. As a test, I removed the redirection part in the dockerfile ENTRYPOINT i.e. removed "service nginx start | " . Upon rebuild, run and invoking the endpoint, I still get the same Broken Pipe error. Also, the above config worked every time thus far. Should I still separate the containers and if so, how should I redirect from Nginx port 8080 to the REST service endpoint?

Comment: I've the same error but not using Python. Are you on a Mac? If yes, can you follow the steps [here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/troubleshoot/) and post the docker logs?